# iPhone repeat call of a select code

Tags: iphone, uitableview, call

Lets say i have a little bit of code I would like to repeat a number of times. How should I best include this in my iPhone app to only have to write this once?

Its a typical TableView Controller App.

```
//Set Icon
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,25,20,20)];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico-date.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Regards

Comment: There is a memory caching issue with images and imageNamed:. You should probably use imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForResource:ofType:.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806374/iphone-most-memory-effecient-way-to-initialize-an-image.

Comment: Sorry I meant: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ico-date" ofType:@"png"]].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options:

1) Create a static C function to do it

```
static UIImageView* myfunc(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat w, CGFloat h,
  NSString* name, NSString* type, UIView* parent) {
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
      CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]; 
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
      pathForResource:name ofType:type]];
    [self.view addSubView:imgView];
    [imgView release];
    return imgView;
}
```

2) Create a C macro

```
#define CREATE_ICON_VIEW(parent,x,y,w,h,name) \
  ...
```

3) Create an Objective-C static method

```
// in @interface section
+ (UIImageView*)addIconWithRect:(CGRect)rect name:(NSString*)name
  type:(NSString*)type toView:(UIView*)view;

// in @implementation section
+ (UIImageView*)addIconWithRect:(CGRect)rect name:(NSString*)name
  type:(NSString*)type toView:(UIView*)view {
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
  imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
    pathForResource:name ofType:type]];
  [self.view addSubView:imgView];     }
  [imgView release];
  return imgView;
}

// somewhere in app code
[MyClass addIconWithRect:CGMakeRect(0,0,32,32) name:@"ico-date"
  type:@"png" toView:parentView];
```

4) Create an Objective-C category on UIImage or UIImageView

5) Create a method on the view that is to have a UIImageView added

```
- (void)addIconWithRect:(CGRect)rect name:(NSString*)name type:(NSString*)type {
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
  imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
    pathForResource:name ofType:type]];
  [self.view addSubView:imgView];     }
  [imgView release];
  return imgView;
}
```

6) Create a Helper class

Like option (3) but put the static methods in a separate class that's just for utility methods for repeated sections of code eg call the helper class "UIUtils".

7) Use a C inline function

```
static inline UIImageView* myfunc(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat w, CGFloat h,
  NSString* name, NSString* type, UIView* parent) {
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
      CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]; 
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
      pathForResource:name ofType:type]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView]; 
    [imgView release];
    return imgView;
}
```

8) Use a loop to execute the same code repeatedly

9) Use an ordinary non-static Objective-C method

Personally I would go for none of these for your particular example and just write it out long-hand, unless it is repeated more than ten times in a file in which case I might go for (3).  If its used in a lot of files I might go for (6).

Edit: Expanded descriptions for (3) and (6) and note about when I use (6).

Edit: Added options 8 & 9.  Fixed memory leaks and some mistakes.

Edit: Updated code to use imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageNamed.

Comment: You can pass a `CGRect` in the C functions.

Comment: on the 3) Create an Objective-C static method, where does the first bit go, appDelegate? and then what do i put in for 'MyClass'?

Comment: It's a static method so it's eg "XYZAppDelegate" (the *class name*) NOT eg "appDelegate" the variable name where I wrote MyClass.

Comment: but if i was implementing #3, 1) Where do i paste the above method, will it run from myAppAppDelegate and then i can call it from wherever using "[MyClass addIconWithRect:CGMakeRect(0,0,32,32) name:@"ico-date.png"
  toView:parentView];"

??

Comment: The (+) symbol means static method.  All methods, whether static or not, must be both declared in an @interface section, and also implemented in an @implementation section.  If you're calling it from lots of places consider placing it in its own separate class, (which is what I mean by "making a Helper class") and calling that UIUtils or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways

- Sub-classing

Stick this in a base class and just inherit from that, no muss no fuss

- Shared Method

Parametrize the use of `self` and instead pass the UIView* as a parameter you want to be doing the adding to.  Then stick that method in a single class accessible from all over and call it only when appropriate.

- Category

Create a category like UIImageView+Icon and put the code there, then you can shorten it to something like `[self.view addSubview:[UIImageView icon:@"ico-date.png"]]`